# Under Tensorflow 2.0, how to visualize two scalars in the graphs side by side (left and right, instead of up and down)?

Tags: python, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

with the code:

```
with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.scalar('train_loss', train_loss, step = epoch)
  tf.summary.scalar('val_loss', val_loss, step = epoch)
writer.flush()
```

The two scalars are visualized in the two graphs up and down as shown in the image. [image]

But I wish the two graphs shown side by side, which is easier to compare.

Answer (score 1):

add the same prefix with a slash before the name, e.g. add '1/'.

```
with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.scalar('1/train_loss', train_loss, step = epoch)
  tf.summary.scalar('1/val_loss', val_loss, step = epoch)
writer.flush()
```